# UiLocalNotifcations - malicious or unintended scheduling

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uilocalnotification

After reading the official docs I understand that If I schedule more than 64 notifications  the OS only keeps the soonest 64... Out of interest what if an app (malicious or not) scheduled a large number (say 64) of local notications (which could also be potentially repeating) - how could a user cancel these if the app is badly coded and doesn't cancel them itself?? Would a restart destroy any scheduled notifications?

Seemingly a badly coded or malicious app could schedule a large number of repeating and annoying notifications for any date in the future, and if not coded correctly even after app deletion these notifications would still be scheduled?

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A restart will not destroy the notifications, But when the device is turned off when the notification expires, the notification will never show up. 
I dont think you're going to find such a bad coded app in the App Store, Apple wouldn't approve an app like that.
If so, could you give us an example?

And if its your own app, you can cancel all the notifications of your app with: [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];

Comment: Indeed, I don't have a direct example- just I'm thinking its quite possible to have an app schedule notifications that repeat and never cancel them! Not good! Surely deleting the app should destroy any scheduled?

Comment: I will make a simple notification app today and I will give it a try. I let you know the result!

Comment: I tried it, but the notifications are not destroyed when you remove the app. But if you first create the notifications, then remove the app and then if you install the app WITH the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];` then the notifications will be canceled.

Comment: Interesting thank you! I suppose bad programming or malicious design could have up to 64 repeating notifications that keep notifying you!?

Comment: You're welcome. Apple should auto cancel all notifications, when the user deletes the app I think!